# Изменить значение тега

Tags: webbrowser, delphi-7

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, как можно поменять значение тега на странице, загруженной в Webbrowser?

`<LI class="default" data-id="1V5wI8NVTh">1234</LI>`

Нужно 1234 поменять на 4567, например. Пробовал так, но текст добавляется к прежнему, а мне нужно заменить:

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc, Arr, Elem : Variant;
  STag, SClass : String;
  a : Integer;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.OleObject.document; 
  STag := 'LI';
  SClass := 'default';

Arr := Doc.getElementsByTagName(STag);
for a := 0 to Arr.length - 1 do begin
Elem := Arr.item(a);
if Elem.className = SClass then begin

 Elem.insertAdjacentText('AfterBegin', '5678');

end;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому, что insert по определению вставляет)

removeAttribute/setAttribute в помощь

Comment: @isaev спасибо,подскажите еще как использовать? пока сделал так:
 Elem.InnerText:='5678';
вроде работает =)

Comment: @stud что не так? Все же работает.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci  хочу узнать, как это можно сделать с помощью removeAttribute/setAttribute  =)

Comment: @stud никогда не делал, по привычке парсю обычно регулярками такие вещи... Посмотрел, какие методы есть в наличии, и предположил, что можно убить его полностью, потом вставить нужный.

InnerText в глаза не бросился.